# Unable to use UIVibrancyEffect with tableView header text label

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, header, uivibrancyeffect

I'm trying to crate a blurry header in my UITableView with a text label that has the vibrancyEffect, but with this code all I get is a blurry header without any text labels...
What's wrong? :)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Header Background color
    view.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // header Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //Header blur
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
    visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.frame = header.bounds;
    [header addSubview:visualEffectView];

    // Text vibrancyEffect
    UIVibrancyEffect *vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];
    UIVisualEffectView *vibrancyEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancyEffect];
    vibrancyEffectView.frame=header.textLabel.frame;
    [vibrancyEffectView.contentView addSubview:header.textLabel];
    [visualEffectView.contentView addSubview:vibrancyEffectView];

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is late...but you set the text to a clear color. What did you expect this to do?   :)

```
header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Anyway my suggestion would be to try something like this:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
[header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
header.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//making background clear, and then placing a blur view across the entire header (execpt the uilabel)
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView;
view.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds;
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[view addSubview:blurEffectView];

[view bringSubviewToFront:header.textLabel];
[view sendSubviewToBack:blurEffectView];
```

Comment: For me this was helpful knowing to set `header.tintColor = clearColor`. Helpful tip.